# How to get regex match on my scenario

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a url that has extra characters after a particular base url string. The base can be either '/home' or '/home/accounts/{numeric_account_id}'. I don't need to capture any matches; I just want to test whether there is a match.

I made a regex of:

```
r'^/home(/accounts/\d+)?(/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)+/?$'
```

Some examples are:

1. '/home' => should not match
2. '/home/' => should not match
3. '/home/accounts/123' => should not match
4. '/home/accounts/123/' => should not match
5. '/home/x' => should match
6. '/home/accounts/123/x' => should match

With my regex above, it incorrectly matches 3 & 4. I tried changing the '?' after accounts group to '*', but that doesn't help. It seems that the last group is greedily matching cases 3 & 4.

What is the correct regex?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, but if the trailing characters are (/accounts/\d+), I definitely want it to match the earlier group, and not get greedily consumed by the last group.

Comment: But you're not looking to capture any matches anyways.

Comment: is the data after always numeric?

Comment: the account # is always numeric. the data after the base can be any valid url substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^/home(?:(?!/accounts/)|/accounts/\d+)(?:/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)+/?$
```

It will match `/home`, then either:

`(?!/accounts/)`: an empty string that doesn't have `/accounts/` coming next, or

`/accounts/\d+`: `/accounts/` followed by numbers.

After that, match any characters allowed in the path.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cV3eR9/1)

Comment: Wow you're a stud! Thanks!

Comment: @jacob No problem, glad to have helped :)

Comment: +1, Nice work tying the requirements together into one regex   :)